# How to get usage of quotas with java implementation on OpenStack

Tags: java, implementation, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I want to learn java codes how to "show quota details for user" on OpenStack API.

I can implement quota limit :

```
String zone = ConfigFactory.load().getString("openstackZone");
NovaApi novaApiClient = getNovaApi(userId, projectId);
Optional<? extends QuotaApi> quotaOptional= novaApiClient.getQuotaExtensionForZone(zone);
Quota quota = quotaOptional.get().getByTenant(ProjectBD.findById(projectId).getProjectId());
ConsoleObjectMapper.getMapper().map(quota, showQuotaBean);
```

but I cant quotas for usage.
For example, I get instance (number), security group(number), ram(GB), volume(number) limit etc. But I cant get information of usage by JAVA code.

```
                 (I can't get) (I can get)
                    Usage        Limit
İnstance              4           10
Security Group        3           20
RAM                512.0 MB      50.0 GB
Volume                5           10
```

Can you help me?

Thanks.